# How to access the data grid inside a custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms, krypton-toolkit

I'm a newbie and I decided to enhance my program's GUI using Krypton Toolkit.
I was able to load it into my project.
The issue that I have created a control with name `mycontrol` which have a KryptonDataGridView with name `mydatagrid`.

In my form, I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : KryptonForm
{
    private KryptonPage[] mycontrolpage;
    private Control mycontrolcontent;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private KryptonPage NewmycontrolPage()
    {
        mycontrolcontent = new mycontrol();
        KryptonPage page = new KryptonPage("mypage", null, "OS mypage");
        // Add the control for display inside the page
        mycontrolcontent.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        page.Controls.Add(mycontrolcontent);

        // Document pages cannot be docked or auto hidden
        page.ClearFlags(KryptonPageFlags.DockingAllowAutoHidden | KryptonPageFlags.DockingAllowDocked);

        return page;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Setup docking functionality
        KryptonDockingWorkspace w = kryptonDockingManager.ManageWorkspace(kryptonDockableWorkspace);
        kryptonDockingManager.ManageControl(kryptonPanel, w);
        kryptonDockingManager.ManageFloating(this);

        mycontrolpage = new KryptonPage[] { NewmycontrolPage() };
        kryptonDockingManager.AddToWorkspace("Workspace", mycontrolpage);
    }
}
```

My problem is how to access the grid in `mycontrol`?

Comment: We would need to see the code of your `mycontrol` class, at least the part that is related to the KryptonDataGridView child control. That being said, as a start, you should declare your variable of type `mycontrol`, not `Control`. Replace `private Control mycontrolcontent` with `private mycontrol mycontrolcontent`, that could solve your problem if you just can't access the properties of that object. One last thing, you should use meaningful names for your controls and variables; don't use names like `mycontrol` as it has no meaning to someone else (might be you in the future) reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

Without some code, You could always view the Examples..
Or
Some code snippets:

```
    internal ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonDataGridView dgvRules;
```

Then...

```
            int offset = dgvRules.Rows.Add((bool)condition, name, description, applied);
            KryptonDataGridViewCheckBoxCell dataGridViewCell = dgvRules.Rows[offset].Cells[0] as KryptonDataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            if (condition == Tribool.Unknown
                || accumulationRules[offset] == Tribool.Unknown)
            {
                dataGridViewCell.ReadOnly = condition == Tribool.Unknown;
                dataGridViewCell.ThreeState = true;
                dataGridViewCell.Value = CheckState.Indeterminate;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridViewCell.Value = (CheckState)accumulationRules[offset];
            }
```